# How to implement custom events in F# on the compact framework?

Tags: f#, compact-framework

I tried following the example given on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233189.aspx), but my code does not compile on the compact framework. It does compile on the normal framework, though.

```
type StorageComponent(game) =
    inherit GameComponent(game)

let title_storage_acquired_event = new Control.DelegateEvent<StorageEventHandler>()
```

Error message:

The type 'DelegateEvent' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the hint from Brian, it looks that the types `DelegateEvent<'Delegate>` and `Event<'Delegate, 'Args>` are not supported on .NET Compact Framework. This would mean that you cannot declare an event that uses an explicitly specified delegate type.

However, you can still use the `Event<'T>` type which creates an event of type `Handler<'T>` (which is a generic delegate type representing methods with two parameters of types `obj` and `'T`):

```
type StorageComponent(game) = 
  inherit GameComponent(game) 

  let titleStorageAcquiredEvent = 
    new Event<StorageEventArgs>() 

  [<CLIEvent>] // If you want to create C# compatible event
  member x.TitleStorageAcquired = 
    titleStorageAcquiredEvent.Publish()
```

Assuming that the declaration of `StorageEventHandler` looks like this:

```
delegate void StorageEventHandler(object sender, StorageEventArgs args);
```

The example above should create more or less an equivalent code (with the only difference that it uses generic `Handler<_>` delegate type instead of your own `StorageEventHandler`).

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, thanks. One thing that is not so nice with F# events is that the type of handlers must be Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Control.Handler<T>, IIRC. Used from C# (or other .NET languages), it might have been easier to use System.EventHandler<T>, instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the code in the CTP

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharp-2.0.0.0\source\fsharp\FSharp.Core\event.fs
```

it will offer some clues (I'm guessing NETCF does not have `del.DynamicInvoke`).  It might also offer clues as to what to do instead; I'm not sure, but hopefully someone else will chime in with a full answer.